# Another way to compare numbers that have input in same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some kind of AP in Computer Science and I've started on coding/programming with Python. I briefly used C++ for few years and now I switched to Python. I don't really remember where I stopped with C++ but that's irrelevant now. Anyways, I have this task that says: "Write program that loads number N, then N numbers and prints number that has the highest value between them. Number N has input in one line and line underneath loads  N numbers with same space between them. None of the numbers will be greater than 100. Number N will be greater than 2."

I wrote this code;

```
`n = int (input())
max = 2
for i in range (1, n+1, 1):
    x=map(int,input().split())
    if x>max: x=max
print (max)
`
```

which returned this error:

> 5
>
> 2 87 12 90 55
>
> File "C:\Users\Mariee.Marija-PC\Documents\Python\19-4.py", line 5, in 
>        if x>max: x=max
>
> TypeError: unorderable types: map() > int()

that was totally expected because I know I can't compare those two as they are clearly not comparable (which again, I am very aware of).

So my question is, is there any other way that N number could be put in one line and then N numbers could be put in the same line but you can compare them (if that makes any sense).

[P.S. Also I'm ultimately sorry if my english was bad.]

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` is a map (similar to a list) of integers, but you are comparing it with a single integer.

In order to loop over the values of `x` you should use a for loop:

```
for x in map(int, input().split()):
    if x > max:
        max = x
```

Comment: It did help in some sort. Now when I type in numbers that are supposed to be in one line/that are mapped (2 87 12 90 55) I have to press enter 5-8 times and then it returns result but result is 2. Any help with that?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a max method in Python, and no need to re-create a max function like you have to do in C/C++. Just apply the max method

```
n = int (input())
print (max(map(int,input().split())))
```